# non-scalar type requested in C

Tags: c

When I tried to compile this code, an error:conversion to non-scalar type requested appeared. This error referred to line:

```
func( record);
```

May I know what is wrong in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student 
{
 int id;
 char name[30];
 float percentage;
};
void func(struct student record); 

int main() 
{

 struct student record[2];
 func( record);
 return 0;
 }     

 void func(struct student record[]) {
 int i;
 record[0].id=1;
 strcpy(record[0].name, "lembu");
 record[0].percentage = 86.5;


 record[1].id=2;
 strcpy(record[1].name, "ikan");
 record[1].percentage = 90.5;


 record[2].id=3;
 strcpy(record[2].name, "durian");
 record[2].percentage = 81.5;

 for(i=0; i<3; i++)
 {
     printf("     Records of STUDENT : %d \n", i+1);
     printf(" Id is: %d \n", record[i].id);
     printf(" Name is: %s \n", record[i].name);
     printf(" Percentage is: %f\n\n",record[i].percentage);
 }

}
```

Comment: Fix your function declaration, it should include `[]` if you are passing it an array of records.

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype for `func` says:

```
void func(struct student record);
```

It should be:

```
void func(struct student record[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have conflicting function declarations.

```
void func(struct student record[])
```

is equivalent to

```
void func(struct student * record)
```

But your initial declaration was

```
void func(struct student record);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're declaring the function you do so like:

```
void func(struct student record);
```

but when you go to use it you're passing a

```
struct student record[2];
```

While you do define at as

```
 void func(struct student record[]) {
```

by that time it's too late, the compiler takes the declaration, regardless of the later definition.

Add a [] to the declaration:

```
void func(struct student record[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes

```
 void func(struct student record[]);
```

and

```
 int main() 
 {
     struct student record[3];
```

the full code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 struct student 
 {
     int id;
     char name[30];
     float percentage;
  };
 void func(struct student record[]); 

 int main() 
 {
     struct student record[3];
     func( record);
     return 0;
 }     

 void func(struct student record[]) {
     int i;
     record[0].id=1;
     strcpy(record[0].name, "lembu");
     record[0].percentage = 86.5;


     record[1].id=2;
     strcpy(record[1].name, "ikan");
      record[1].percentage = 90.5;


      record[2].id=3;
      strcpy(record[2].name, "durian");
      record[2].percentage = 81.5;

      for(i=0; i<3; i++)
      {
          printf("     Records of STUDENT : %d \n", i+1);
          printf(" Id is: %d \n", record[i].id);
          printf(" Name is: %s \n", record[i].name);
          printf(" Percentage is: %f\n\n",record[i].percentage);
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because the compiler couldn't convert from `student *` to `student` when doing the matching of the actual and formal parameters of `func`:

In the function prototype the parameter is declared with type `student`. In the definition, it is declared as an array, which in C decays to a pointer.

Fix the function prototype so that it declares exactly what you want:

```
void func(struct student record[]);
```